# How do I put a application bar on a pivot page?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm learning Windows Phone 8. At this point I don't use the MVVM pattern. I want to add a application bar to my pivot page (declared as myPivotPage). I've added programmatically a application bar to a PannormaPage (myPanoramaPage) . It was very simple. I worote the code bellow:

```
   myApplicationBar = new ApplicationBar();
   myApplicationBar.IsMenuEnabled = true;
   myApplicationBar.IsVisible = true;

   addIconButton = new ApplicationBarIconButton();
   addIconButton.Text = "Add";
   addIconButton.IconUri = new Uri("/Assets/AppBar/add.png", UriKind.Relative);
   addIconButton.IsEnabled = true;

   MyPanoramaPage.ApplicationBar = myApplicationBar; // the important line of code
```

When I want to add the application bar to a pivot page (still programmatically) I try doing that in the "important" commented line something like

```
   myPivotPage.ApplicationBar = myApplicationBar;
```

The problem is that the myPivotPage object does not contain a definition for ApplicationBar. I've tried adding it from the XAML code and using it on the code behind but no results so far.

Any ideas?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this. As far as I know `ApplicationBar` is associated with your Page, but `Pivot` is just a control on your Page.
You can do it by defining different application bars in your resources section:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources> 

<shell:ApplicationBar x:Key="firstPivotTabApplicationBar" IsVisible="True"> 
    ...
</shell:ApplicationBar> 

<shell:ApplicationBar x:Key="firstPivotTabApplicationBar" IsVisible="True"> 
    ...
</shell:ApplicationBar>
```

and then within the `SelectionChanged` event in your pivot control you could do like this:

```
private void MainPagePivot_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) 
{
string pivot_Item;

switch (_mainPagePivot.SelectedIndex)
{
    case 0:
        pivot_Item= "firstPivotTabApplicationBar";
        break;

    case 1:
        pivot_Item= "secondPivotTabApplicationBar";
        break;

    default:
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
}

ApplicationBar = (ApplicationBar)Resources[pivot_Item]; 
}
```

You could refer here for more:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394036(v=vs.105).aspx

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The `ApplicationBar` lives in the shell of your program. It exists everywhere, but no where...

```
<spooky wind breeze blows by/>
```

In order to create it just new up an `ApplicationBar` on your loaded event.

Don't create it in `XAML`.... Do it in `C#`.

Now this is blasphemous if you are following `MVVM`. However, there is good reason for it.

If you build your `ApplicationBar` in `XAML` then you won't be able to modify it. If you do explosions ensue.

Build it in `C#` like my example below and you will be able to dynamically add buttons, hide it, ect.

```
//In your w/e method or event

ApplicationBar = new ApplicationBar();
ApplicationBar .IsMenuEnabled = true;
ApplicationBar .IsVisible = true;

ApplicationBarIconButton addIconButton = new ApplicationBarIconButton();
addIconButton.Text = "Add";
addIconButton.IconUri = new Uri("/Assets/AppBar/add.png", UriKind.Relative);
addIconButton.IsEnabled = true;

ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(addIconButton); //not to sure on this line, I did it from memory.
```